# How to do Facelets-like template composition using Tiles?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tiles

I'm doing a Java Web Project using Spring, JSP and Tiles. In our last project we have used Facelets `<ui:composition>` and `<ui:define>` tags to include JS and CSS libraries in the header of a template. I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same using Tiles.

Here's an example of the Facelets master template what I'm trying to do:

```xml
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">MediMercado</ui:insert></title>
        <link href="${request.contextPath}/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <ui:insert name="additional-js"></ui:insert>
    </head>
    <body>
         <ui:insert name="content">
             <ui:include src="main-content.xhtml"/>
         </ui:insert>
    </body>
</html>
```

Page template:

```xml
<ui:composition template="/layout/layout.xhtml"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:define name="additional-js">
        <script src="${request.contextPath}/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>Just an example</h1>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

So in this example the jquery library in our page template is been included in the HTML head of the master template.

How can we do this using Tiles?

Comment: JSTL, being mainly a flow control and utility taglib, offers completely nothing with regard to templating. So forget it. I've removed JSTL references from the question so that it's less noisy. Further, Facelets is technically the successor of JSP, so I really wonder why you're falling back to JSP here. Apart from Tiles, which is basically a JSP taglib, you can also consider to take a look at FreeMarker or Velocity, which are distinct template technologies. But sinde I do neither of them all, I can't go in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections!. Im currently trying to understand the Tiles Tutorial, basically we change from Facelets because we use Spring Security and facelets give us some problems with the sessions. As i cannot decide the use of Tiles, I have to use it!

Comment: You mean the unnecessary session creation by Facelets? This is been fixed in Mojarra 2.1.x. Consider updating the JSF libs http://javaserverfaces.java.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Tiles Tutorial](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/basic/pages.html) cover this theme.

(Hint: In Tiles the files are more separated than in JSF)

Comment: Thanks, although is not the answer , Im reading the tutorial to find an answer.

Comment: For now Im putting the Javascript code on the body. I couldnt find anything that could help me in the Tiles tutorial.